# Remove viewport noise

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, vertex-colors

I'm working with color sensitive data in vertex colors, and the only way I can retrieve these colors in real-time is to capture them off the mesh they're applied to (otherwise, I have to locate the vertex in an exported format or keep a list). They're currently not possible to retrieve in-editor like weights are, to my knowledge.

Unfortunately, there's a subtle noise over the 3D viewport that was not present in 2.79 and will not go away in 2.8. Under flat lighting, proper color sequencing, and colors from vertex, any given point on the mesh or background altered by a noise overlay that slightly skews the actual data:

[image]

It's difficult to make out, but up close any given pixel appear to vary in color by one of three variants, of which only one is correct (this presentation may also be altered by any compression added on upload, but believe me, it's there)

Where is this noise option specified? It's been a battle disabling various and superfluous rendering options applied to 2.8 over older editions. I need a functional workspace, not a pretty one.